# Excel VBA filter reset works in Immediate window but not in Sub BeforeClose

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the following code to reset any validation and/or autofiltering before my workbook closes:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Query").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Clear

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Table").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Clear

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Table").ShowAllData

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Query").Activate

    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

However, 'Worksheets("Table").ShowAllData' only seems to work in the immediate window.  When I close the program after filtering the table on sheet "Table" and open it up again, I get

`We found a problem with some content in "Book1.xlsm".  Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?  If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.`

This didn't happen at first and it seems to have no cause.  Why does the filter reset work in the immediate window, but not in my subroutine?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

never use `On Error Resume Next` or you will never learn anything

you need to check to see if `Autofilter` is on first because it's a toggle...

```
  If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
  End If
```

or

```
  If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
  End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! However, nether of these work either.  `Worksheets("Table").AutoFilterMode = False` works in the Immediate window, just like my original code, but it completely removes the filter arrows all together which i'd like to avoid.  Same error message with the sub.

Comment: why not just use ActiveSheet?

Comment: do you know how to set a break point and use F8 to step thru it line by line?

Answer (score 0):

No need to have so many OERN `On Error Resume Next`. Just one will do.

I tried this

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Query").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Clear
    Worksheets("Table").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Worksheets("Table").FilterMode Then Worksheets("Table").ShowAllData

    Worksheets("Query").Activate

    ThisWorkbook.Save
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

and I did not get any errors. Try it.

> > We found a problem with some content in "Book1.xlsm".  Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?  If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

If you still get an error then it is not because of this piece of code. You need to see the report as to what was repaired. I have a feeling one of your `DataValidation` list is causing this problem. Like I said, check the repair report. If the report says that the `Datavalidation` was repaired then you need to check that.